# Update Sharepoint Page Header Author using Power Automate

Tags: sharepoint, power-automate

I would like to update the Page Header Author of our SharePoint intranet news posts. I decided to try using Power Automate to achieve this.

[image: PageHeader Author]

It seems like this isn't in the properties of the page, but rather in the page content itself.

Is there any way this can be achieved using Power Automate?

Comment: It will be difficult task to update it using Power automate, which can be easily done using PowerShell. Let me know if you are ok with PowerShell approach and I will provide the script for same.

Comment: Thanks for your offer, I'd gladly take a look at the PowerShell code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use PnP PowerShell to set SharePoint page Author Byline. Here's the sample PnP PowerShell script for same:

```
    Param(
        [Parameter(mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$SiteUrl,
        [Parameter(mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$PageName,
        [Parameter(mandatory = $true)]
        [string]$UserEmail
    )

    function Set-PageAuthorByline {

        # Connect to the site
        Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteUrl;

        # If there is an error in the connection then return
        if ($null -eq $(Get-PnPConnection).ConnectionType) {
            return;
        }

        # Get the page object from the specified page name / url 
        $page = Get-PnPPage -Identity $PageName;

        # Return if page is not found
        if ($null -eq $page) {
            Write-Error "Page Name is not valid";
            return;
        }

        # Get the required user from the User Information list
        Write-Host "Getting user information from User Information list..." -ForegroundColor Yellow;
        $user = Get-PnPUser | Where-Object Email -eq $UserEmail;

        if ($null -ne $user) {
            Write-Host "Got user information from User Information list." -ForegroundColor Yellow;
        }
        else {
            # If not user is not present in User Information list then add the user to the list
            # This will not affect any permissions to the site
            Write-Host "User information not present in User Information list, hence adding..." -ForegroundColor Yellow;
            $user = New-PnPUser -LoginName $UserEmail; 

            # Return if the user is not found / email address is incorrect
            if ($null -eq $user) {
                Write-Error "User Name is not valid";
                return;
            }
        }

        Write-Host "Setting page header author..." -ForegroundColor Yellow;

        # Set the Authors and AuthorByLine properties of the PageHeader
        # Both these are string properties
        $page.PageHeader.Authors = "[{`"id`":`"$($user.LoginName)`"}]";
        $page.PageHeader.AuthorByLine = "[`"$($user.Email)`"]";

        # Save the chnages and publish the page
        $page.Save();
        $page.Publish();

        Write-Host "Done." -ForegroundColor Green;
        Disconnect-PnPOnline;
    }

    Set-PageAuthorByline;

    # Set-Page-Author-Byline.ps1 -SiteUrl https://tenantname.sharepoint.com/sites/sitename -PageName Page-1.aspx -UserEmail user@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com
```

**Source**: [Set Page Author Byline](https://pnp.github.io/script-samples/spo-set-page-authorbyline/README.html?tabs=pnpps)

Before running above script, you have to install PnP PowerShell by following: [Installing PnP PowerShell](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/articles/installation.html)